# Extensions methods using implicits do not compile with Scala 3

Tags: scala, extension-methods, implicit, scala-3

Following code compiles fine with Scala 2.13.12, but not with Scala 3.3.1:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Types {
  trait Vector3f
  implicit class Vector3fOps(v: Vector3f) {
    def *(rhs: Double): Vector3f = ???
  }
}

import Types._

object Compute {
  case class Matrix3f(col1: Vector3f, col2: Vector3f, col3: Vector3f) {
    def * (x: Double): Vector3f = col1 * x
  }

  implicit class Vec3Ops(v: Vector3f) {
    def * (m: Matrix3f): Vector3f = ???
  }
}
```

The error is:

> Found:    (x : Double)
>
> Required: Compute.Matrix3f [14:42]

The code compiles fine when I merge the objects `Types` and `Compute` into one, when I move the `import Types._` into the `object Compute` or when I remove the `Vec3Ops`.

It seems `Vec3Ops.*` somehow hides the `Vector3fOps.*` for Scala 3 compiler.

Why is this? Is this a bug in Scala 3 compiler, or is there some reason for the new behavior?